# PC program to take photos of documents, correct perspective, rotate and crop them automatically

Tags: windows, image-processing, scanning

I know of several mobile apps designed to tidy up photos of documents, snapped directly from a phone camera, but I'd like a PC program to do the same thing. I already have a bunch of photos of documents as image files on my PC, which are at higher quality than my phone could ever take!

I can do this in Photoshop fairly easily but it takes time; I would like something more automatic, something that'll assume I have a photo of one rectangular thing, and work out the correct transform for me.

Absolute best form would be a program that can take image file paths as command line arguments and pump out fixed images without interaction, or a minimal GUI app with ability to work in batches. I don't want to have to spend ages setting up each conversion.

I would prefer for the output to be image files but PDFs would be fine too.

Platform needs to be Windows.

Comment: What's the difference between perspective correction and rotation? Also, what can't done automatically in Photoshop?

Comment: By 'perspective correction' I mean that the camera is never perfectly flat on to the document so there's a little (sometimes a lot!) of perspective warping, which isn't as simple to correct as applying rotation - it's skew, plus a bit of magic. This kind of thing: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/keystoning/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware it was called keystone correction!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (Free, open source, cross-platform, CLI) to post-process all your scanned images at once:

- [auto-orientation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8100)
- [trim whitespace](https://askubuntu.com/a/351772/44876): `convert input.png -trim output.png`

Comment: Ah, I've used ImageMagick for some format conversion before, didn't know it could do this kind of thing. I'll investigate - thanks!

Comment: ImageMagick is a great piece of software, but Adobe Photoshop is probably even better and can be scripted/automated as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use python and OpenCV to detect the document orientation and perspective, assuming that the document will normally be rectangular and have the longest edges vertical quicker on a grey scale version - this will give you the transform values to use and then you can apply the same.

There is an example, (in C), on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656698/perspective-correction-in-opencv-using-python

Answer (score 0):

2 options I found so far:

1- Free Option: PerspectiveImageCorrection. https://sourceforge.net/projects/perspectiveimg/
2- Paid Option: Perspective Pilot.
https://www.colorpilot.com/perspective.html

and to cover all requirements, I would use option 1 and a free software called "PhotoScap" combined.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar need and have found [Scan Tailor](https://scantailor.org/) OSS.

It is not entirely automated. You use `scantailor.exe` GUI app to create a "project file" that contains configuration, then launch `scantailor-cui.exe` CUI that loads the file to do batch processing. (processing can be completed in GUI too)

- https://vimeo.com/12524529
- [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)
- [scantailor FAQ: How can ScanTailor be automated? (...) Is there a command-line version of Scan Tailor?](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor/wiki/FAQ#11-how-can-scantailor-be-automated-i-have-programmed-an-application--calling-some-others-in-a-batch-is-there-a-command-line-version-of-scan-tailor)